# Regex - extracting Text

Tags: regex, text, extract

I was using

```
(?<=Activties</h3>)[\w\s\/\,\-\.]*
```

to extract the text from here but I only get the 1st line. I would like to like to capture all lines up until the next "h3 style". It is not important whether the "br" is captured or not

```
  <h3 style="margin: 10px 0px 0px;">Beach Type</h3> sand <h3 style="margin: 10px 0px 0px;">Facilities</h3> Cafes/restaurant<br>Toilets<br>Disabled toilets<br> <h3 style="margin: 10px 0px 0px;">Activities</h3> Swimming<br>Fishing<br>Snorkeling<br> <h3 style="margin: 10px 0px 0px;">Nature and Wildlife</h3> Grandes Rocques is located at the start of Guernsey's 14km west coast footpath and cycle route. Port Soif Nature Trail and the Saumarez Nature trail are also located nearby. There is a diverse range of wildlife here. The first live Green Turtle to be rec <h3 style="margin: 10px 0px 0px;">Parking</h3> 200 spaces are available <h3 style="margin: 10px 0px 0px;">Water Quality</h3> Excellent <h3 style="margin: 10px 0px 0px;">Lifeguard</h3> No <h3 style="margin: 10px 0px 0px;">Cleaning and Litter</h3> The beach is cleaned daily by hand in the summer and twice a week in winter. There are litter and dog bins present. <h3 style="margin: 10px 0px 0px;">Awards and Recommendations</h3> Marine Conservation Society Recommended<br>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks for looking

omeganos

Comment: Use HTML Agility Pack instead of regex parsing. Check this link out.http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite a vague question but something like this accomplishes what you're asking:

```
(?<=Activities</h3>)(.*?)<h3
```

You could make the `.*?` more restrictive if you need to. The `.*` means match anything, and `?` means non-greedy (so it will stop at the first `<h3` it finds, not the last one).

Comment: That worked I am left with  Bathing<br>Exploring rock-pools <h3 how do I remove the <h3 though. Sorry for being so vague

Comment: You can take @Nic Wolfe solution and change it like this : `(?<=Activities</h3>)(.*?)(?:<h3)`. **(?:<h3)** means capture '<h3' but don't match it.

Comment: Tried (?<=Activities</h3>)(.*?)(?:<h3) but <h3 still there!

Comment: @AndrewPerry It is not `?:` it should be `?=` that would be then a positive lookahead assertion. `(?<=Activities</h3>)(.*?)(?=<h3)`

Comment: Thanks Nic for the initial answer and many thanks to stema for fine tuning the result

Comment: FYI the text you want (without the `<h3`) is stored in a group, so you could get what you want out of the original solution by looking at the group 1 text rather than the whole match.

Answer (score 0):

1. In which language?
2. Normally it is better to use a HTML/DOM parser to get data from HTML. I am quite sure this is here the case.
3. You don't have the `<>` brackets in your character class. Why should it match the `<br>` tags?
4. Where do you tell the pattern to stop at the next `<h3 style` ?

Comment: not sure which language, I didn't include the brackets yet because that would of included the h3 style and only stopped at the = Including the text "<h3 style" which I didn't want.

Comment: Where do you use the regex? In a programming language or a editor?

Comment: is output from a extraction tool

Comment: And what is it where you write the regex in? What gives you that result?